# Putting Overlay after getting data from AlarmManager call

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, alarmmanager

I have a main activity which shows google map (v2). Periodically I send data and retrieve data using Alarm manager of Android. Once I receive the data from Alarm manager, I need to pass the retrieved location details back to the Google map. How could I do it? Let me know if you require code to understand this.

MapViewActivity.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MapViewActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,
        SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    private boolean started = false;
    private ArrayList<AccelLocData> sensorData;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Button btnStart, btnStop;
    private String provider;

    // File root, dir, sensorFile;
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private FileWriter writer;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntentSender, pendingIntentReceiver;

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Intent alarmIntent,alarmIntent2;

    // private Button btnUpload;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {

            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            databaseHelper.removeAll();


            Log.v("datacount",
                    Integer.toString(databaseHelper.getLocDataCount()));

            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mAccelerometer = sensorManager
                    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

            btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
            btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);

            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services
                                                        // are
                                                        // not available

                int requestCode = 10;
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,
                        this, requestCode);
                dialog.show();

            } else { // Google Play Services are available

                // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of
                // activity_main.xml
                // SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (MapFragment)
                // getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


                // can use for overlay on the map
                List<Double> latList = new ArrayList<Double>();
                latList.add(145.7309593);
                latList.add(146.34);
                latList.add(147.34);

                List<Double> lonList = new ArrayList<Double>();
                lonList.add(-122.6365384);
                lonList.add(-123.6365384);
                lonList.add(-124.6365384);

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    // LatLng latLng = new LatLng(45.7309593, -122.6365384);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latList.get(i).doubleValue(),
                            lonList.get(i).doubleValue());
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    googleMap
                            .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(latLng)
                                    .title("My Spot")
                                    .snippet("This is my spot!")
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
                }

                // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }

                locationManager
                        .requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (started) {

            double x = event.values[0];
            double y = event.values[1];
            double z = event.values[2];

            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

            LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

            provider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            double latitude = 0;
            double longitude = 0;
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
            AccelLocData accelLocData = new AccelLocData(timestamp, x, y, z,
                    latitude, longitude);

            // Log.d("X data","data x:" + data.getX());

            try {
                // writer.write(data.toString());
                 if (databaseHelper != null)
                 databaseHelper.insertLocData(accelLocData);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));






    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStart:

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AccelLocSender.class);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            pendingIntentSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    alarmIntent, 0);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, pendingIntentSender);

            alarmIntent2 = new Intent(context, AccelLocReceiver.class);
            pendingIntentReceiver = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    alarmIntent2, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000, pendingIntentReceiver);

            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            Log.d("startbutton", "cam on click of start");
            started = true;

            // delete all files..
            // start thread to send data

            sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            break;
        case R.id.btnStop:
            try {
                btnStart.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                // btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
                started = false;

                sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

                Context context1 = getApplicationContext();
                AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) context1
                        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager1.cancel(pendingIntentSender);
                alarmManager1.cancel(pendingIntentReceiver);

            //  System.exit(0);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        /*
         * if (writer != null) { try { writer.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
         * // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } }
         */
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*
         * try { Log.d("onresume","called onresume"); writer = new
         * FileWriter(sensorFile, true); } catch (IOException e) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

AccelLocReceiver.java

```
public class AccelLocReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        System.out.println("cmg in AccelLocReceiver");
        Log.i("Alarm receiver", "Came in alarm receiver");
        receiveDataFromServer();

    }

    private void receiveDataFromServer() {
        try {
        // I get this successfully location details here. I use httpclient to send data to php webserver.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

Similarly AccelLocSender class to send the data.

Comment: There are many ways you can send the data but you failed to give any details with what you do with the data you get

Comment: Hi @tyczj , I already know how to get and post the details through server. What I am asking is here is that: I am getting location latitude and longitude from my server. How would I update this details to show overlays in Google maps? I hope I cleared my question now.

Comment: I understand that you know what you did with the data but how do we know what you did with the data, where you got it from, how you got it etc... for us to help you.

Comment: Ok @tyczj, here is the thing. I am making an application like Waze, so if I am notice something unusual (traffic/accident) on the road, I would add the data on the application. My application periodically collects and sends the data to server. When I collect the data, it brings latitude and longitude data about location reported at that place as well as brings data from other people. So, I want to show these new location details on the map. Please let me know if you are still unclear about what i am asking.

Comment: ok let me say this another way where is the data being stored..a database, arraylist, some other method..? is the data coming in from a service or are you doing this in an activity. Show code of what you did

Comment: @tyczj , check above. I have added the code. So, I am already drawing map in initial activity. Now once I retrieve new location details from AccelLocReceiver class, I want to pass those location values to Map. How do I redraw that? The data is stored in database (Central php webserver)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29219/discussion-between-j-modi-and-tyczj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a bit messed up application architecture.

1. You need model. Something that exists outside of `Activity`. `Application` subclass is a good place for that.
2. You should not do network in `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive`. Start a `Service` there or simply call a function in `Application`, that will run a `Thread` if you are not afraid of app being killed when in background.
3. Store data you get from network in local SQLite DB.
4. Create observer pattern for the model and register `Activity` as a listener. When you get a callback, use your `googleMap` object to create any objects you want.

Comment: Thanks @MaciejGorski for your comments. I would make changes according to your suggestions.