# Google map (Google Map Android v2) activity is getting crashed on toggling USB modes

Tags: android, usb, google-maps-android-api-2

I have fallen into a weird situation here and it occurred by-chance. I am currently using Google Map APIs for Android v2 for displaying map fragments. Everything is running fine except the app crashes when user toggles between the USB modes.

The problem is, I am not able to save some of the objects as I cannot override the onSaveInstanceState() in this case. It is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4912) in Google Maps API. I am getting **Null-Pointer-Exception**. The complete logcat is as follows:

```
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{com.octanetech.cortes/com.octanetech.cortes.MapActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.octanetech.cortes.MapActivity.displayPlaces(MapActivity.java:644)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at com.octanetech.cortes.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:158)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-27 18:45:10.289: E/AndroidRuntime(19982):    ... 11 more
04-27 18:45:10.309: W/ActivityManager(2466):   Force finishing activity com.octanetech.cortes/.MapActivity
```

The application is getting crashed only when I resume the map activity, otherwise rest of the application is working fine. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Edit** Adding trimmed MapActivity Class:

```
public class MapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements LocationListener, OnInfoWindowClickListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    OnMarkerClickListener {
// private final BitmapDescriptor markerBitmap = null;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private CameraPosition cameraPosition;
Location currentLocation;
MapView mapView;
Bitmap beaconImage;
Geocoder geocoder;
private Handler mHandler;
protected Marker marker;
ActionBar actionBar;
private Menu menu;
private boolean menuCreated;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    navigate = new NavigateActivity(this);
    context = this;
    currentLocation = new Location("asd");
    currentLocation.setLatitude(0);
    currentLocation.setLongitude(0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    SupportMapFragment f = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    f.setRetainInstance(true);

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    displayPlaces();

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    this.menu = menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mapview_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    setupSearchView(searchItem);
    menuCreated = true;
    return true;
}

private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

    if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    } else {
        searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    }

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchManager != null) {
    }

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // mStatusView.setText("Query = " + newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.list:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
        intent.removeExtra("search");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.bookmark:
        intent = new Intent(adasd.this, BookmarkActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    // Extras.createActualDialogueBox(context, "error", url.length()+"");
    // getPlaces(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadingActivityForPlaces.class);
    mBeaconOptionsPoppedUp = false;
    intent.putExtra("key", query);
    startActivity(intent);
    Extras.searched = true;
    return false;
}

public boolean onClose() {

    return false;
}

protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
    if (mBeaconOptionsPoppedUp) {

        mBeaconOptionsPoppedUp = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    displayPlaces();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Extras.activityPaused();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

private void displayPlaces() {
    if (!Extras.trialMode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (placesMarkers != null) {
            removeMarkers(placesMarkers);
        }
        placesMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        for (GooglePlace i : Extras.googlePlaces) {
            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(i.getPosition()).title(i.getTitle())
                    .snippet(i.getDescription()));
            if (i.equals(Extras.currentGooglePlace)) {

                m.showInfoWindow();
            }
            placesMarkers.add(m);

        }

        for (GooglePlace i : Extras.cortesPlaces) {
            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(i.getPosition()).title(i.getTitle())
                    .snippet(i.getDescription()));
            if (i.equals(Extras.currentGooglePlace)) {

                m.showInfoWindow();
            }
            placesMarkers.add(m);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Here Extras is a class with static objects. The app is getting crashes when accessing **displayPlaces()** function. When **Extras.GooglePlaces** object is accessed a **Null-pointer-exception** is thrown. I have already initialised this object in some other activity, but when user toggles between USB mode it is getting Null and hence null pointer exception.

Comment: show us your MapActivity

Comment: Hi @chopchop . I have shown the trimmed version of my MapActivity. The static object Extras.GooglePlaces is getting Null. Though it is static and I also tried extending its class to Application, but still it did not solve the problem

Comment: static objects are not guaranteed to be retained in your activities lifecycle. If you really need that sort of behaviour (ie one unique object accessible from everywhere), extend Application and initialize it in its onCreate() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` in your code is not `"an issue in Google Maps API"`.

I advise against using `static` keyword except for constants, nested classes and sometimes factory methods. This includes singleton anti-pattern.

You will have to work with your application architecture. chopchop's suggestion is a good start. You may want to check some points from my answer to unrelated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16335191/2183804